# How do I format my headers for an API request using Javscript?

Tags: javascript, oauth, http-headers

I am attempting to utilize [the Discogs API](https://www.discogs.com/developers#page:authentication,header:authentication-oauth-flow) which has the following requirements:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization:
        OAuth oauth_consumer_key="your_consumer_key",
        oauth_nonce="random_string_or_timestamp",
        oauth_signature="your_consumer_secret&",
        oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT",
        oauth_timestamp="current_timestamp",
        oauth_callback="your_callback"
User-Agent: some_user_agent
```

I'm just learning Javascript and will be using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). That documentation explains how to use it well - including how to add a header. My question is, how do I format the proper Discogs requirements?

Here is where I am getting stuck:

```
const discogs_headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            ...
        }
```

How do I add the folowing to that dictionary?

```
Authorization:
        OAuth oauth_consumer_key="your_consumer_key",
        oauth_nonce="random_string_or_timestamp",
        oauth_signature="your_consumer_secret&",
        oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT",
        oauth_timestamp="current_timestamp",
        oauth_callback="your_callback"
```

I tried this and it doesn't work correctly:

```
const discogs_headers = {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Authorization": "OAuth oauth_consumer_key="your_consumer_key", oauth_nonce="random_string_or_timestamp",...
            }
```

Note: I am actually filling in my applications information there, just using the document entries for the purpose of this question. I apologize if this is worded poorly. Please don't hesitate to ask if there is something I can add for clarity.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It didn't work because it's a syntax error.  Note the syntax highlighting in the question itself.  You're trying to use `"` characters in a string which itself is denoted by `"` characters.  You can wrap your string in `'` instead:  `'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="your_consumer_key", ...'`  (Replace the values with your actual values too of course.  Just don't do that here for all to see.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use template literals in the `Authorization` portion like so (abbreviated for simplicity).

```js
const consumerKey = 'your_consumer_key';
const nonce = 'random_string_or_timestamp';

// ...
const discogs_headers = {
  'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  Authorization: `OAuth oauth_consumer_key="${consumerKey}", oauth_nonce="${nonce}"`
};

console.log(discogs_headers);
```

Where, obviously, `consumerKey`, `nonce`, etc. are values associated with your app.  Again, the entire `Authorization` header was not filled out in this answer, but the gist of it is there.